# How to make complex Json fit a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

The backend of my webapp, written in node.js interacts with Json file, with a specific format that I thought not so complex but apparently is.

The structure of my json file is as such :

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "somefield": "ioremipsum",
        "somedate" : "2018-08-23T11:48:00Z",
        "someotherdate" : "2018-08-23T13:43:00Z",
        "somethingelse":"ioremipsum",
        "files": [
          {
            "specificfieldinarray": "ioremipsum",
            "specificotherfieldinarray": "ioremipsum"
          },
          {
            "specificfieldinarray": "ioremipsum",
            "specificotherfieldinarray": "ioremipsum"
          },
          {
            "specificfieldinarray": "ioremipsum",
            "specificotherfieldinarray": "ioremipsum"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I try to make this answer fit a JS object like this :

```js
const file =  require('specificJsonFile.json');

let fileList = file;
```

And I need to loop through my 'files' array, for further treatments, but unfortunately, my JS object looks like this :

```js
{ data:
   [ { somefield: "ioremipsum",
       somedate : "2018-08-23T11:48:00Z",
       someotherdate : "2018-08-23T13:43:00Z",
       somethingelse:"ioremipsum",
       files: [Array] } ] }
```

Please forgive me if this is obvious, for I am still a beginner with JS.

Comment: What kind of loop do you want to use? Are you trying to change the items in files array, or read them for some other use?

Comment: Seems okay to me. Since `files` is a nested array inside an object inside an array which _also_ contains objects, the console log is abbreviated. You should be able to get to your array of files by doing `fileList.data[0].files.<LOOPING METHOD>`

Comment: I just want to read the items for further use.
Currently I try to use a for(var file in files){}.

Comment: @RyanDabler , actually, I can't.
I loop through data like this : ```for( var x in fileList.data){for(var file in x.files){<SOME TREATMENT>}}``` . And none of the treatment in the second loop is reached,also when I try to fit the 'files' array in an object, the variable logs 'undefined' in the console.

Comment: That's because the `for` `in` structure gives you a numerical index, not the element itself. You can use `for` `of` if you want the element or use `fileList.data[x]` in your second loop.

Comment: Well, false alarm, I just was confused with basics of loops through js arrays. Thanks alot nevertheless.

Comment: @Lifz yes, it was absolutely that. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonGrondin no problem :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let fileList = file.data[0].files;
```

This will create an array of only your files array.

You can console.log(fileList)

Or whatever you like with the data.

Based on your comment, try the of keyword instead of in keyword to get the behaviour you expected.

```
for (let file of fileList){
    console.log(file);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Actually, thank you. I misunderstood the fact the var you define is not the item, but the index when looping through arrays. I am still very easily confused by this. I'll accept your answer since you were the first one to do so. Cheers.

Comment: @SimonGrondin __never__ use `for in` on an array!!! This answer is not correct, you should unmark it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: @bambam as per mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in This is only true in an array where the index order is important. Anyway, I updated the answer to use for...of instead of for...in as it is the behaviour closer to what SimonGrondin was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

That's only how console.log logs deep objects. To get a deeper output, you can use util.inspect

```
const util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(yourObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```

To loop each data's files, simply loop data, then its files

```
yourObject.data.forEach(d => {
    d.files.forEach(file => console.log(file));
});
```

Comment: You did, thanks ! I confused myself between indexes and values of arrays

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is nothing wrong there and the console is abbreviating the log.

Try accessing the files list with the following code:

`const filesList = file.data[0].files`

and then

`console.log(filesList)` to check that it's eventually working.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You did, thanks ! I confused myself between indexes and values of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `for` `in`

```
for (item in fileList.data) {
    for (file in fileList.data[item].files) {
         let data = fileList.data[item].files[file];

         // process the data         

    }
}
```

Comment: You did, thanks ! I confused myself between indexes and values of arrays